# X_train, y_train from ImageDataGenerator (Keras)

Tags: python, keras, cnn

Can I have X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test from data_generator?
Here is my code:

```
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. / 255, 
    shear_range = 0.2, 
    zoom_range = 0.2, 
    horizontal_flip = True,
    vertical_flip = True,
    rotation_range = 180,
    width_shift_range = 0.2,
    height_shift_range = 0.2,
    validation_split = 0.2) 

train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir, 
    target_size =(img_width, img_height), 
    batch_size = batch_size,
    shuffle = True,
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    seed = 42,
    subset='training')

validation_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory( 
    train_data_dir, 
    target_size =(img_width, img_height), 
    batch_size = batch_size,
    shuffle = True,
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    seed = 42,
    subset='validation')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in python 2:

`X_train, y_train = train_generator.next()
 X_test, y_test = validation_generator.next()`

in python 3:

`X_train, y_train = next(train_generator)
X_test, y_test = next(validation_generator)`

Answer (score 2):

As per the above answer, the below code just gives 1 batch of data.

```
X_train, y_train = next(train_generator)
X_test, y_test = next(validation_generator)
```

To extract full data from the train_generator use below code -

step 1: Install tqdm

```
pip install tqdm
```

Step 2: Store the data in X_train, y_train variables by iterating over the batches

```
import tqdm
train_generator.reset()
X_train, y_train = next(train_generator)
for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(int(train_generator.n/batch_size)-1)): 
  img, label = next(train_generator)
  X_train = np.append(X_train, img, axis=0 )
  y_train = np.append(y_train, label, axis=0)
print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
```

Comment: I tried this code and it gives an error **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'tuple'**

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
X_train, y_train = train_generator.next()
X_test, y_test = validation_generator.next()
```

y_train, y_test values will be based on the category folders you have in train_data_dir.
Not values will be like 0,1,2,3... mapping to class names in Alphabetical Order.

Otherwise, use below code to get indices map

```
train_generator.class_indices
validation_generator.class_indices
```

Make sure they both are the same.

Answer (score 0):

More of an indirect answer, but maybe helpful to some: Here is a script I use to sort test and train images into the respective (sub) folders to work with Keras and the data generator function (MS Windows).

```
import os
from glob import glob
from shutil import copyfile

############################
# Data stored at...
odir = "C:/origdir/"
# Target dir for test-train split
tdir = "C:/myimages/"
# Test-train-split (= x * maxsamples)
trainsize = 0.8
# Define max numer of samples for test-train
maxsamples = 2500

paths = glob(str(odir)+"*")

for p in paths:
    # get name of dir
    classname = p[p.rfind("\\")+1:]
    ###########################################
    # Gen dirs in tt
    # Check/create dir
    # TEST
    try:
        os.makedirs(str(tdir) + "/val/" + str(classname))
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
    # TRAIN
    try:
        os.makedirs(str(tdir) + "/train/" + str(classname))
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
    # ###########################################
    # COPY
    # train samples
    filelist = os.listdir(p)
    filelist = filelist[:maxsamples]
    tindex = int(trainsize*len(filelist))
    trainfiles = filelist[:tindex]
    testfiles = filelist[tindex:]
    # train
    for f in trainfiles:
        copyfile(p + "/"+  f, str(tdir) + "/train/" + str(classname) + "/" + f)
        #os.remove(p + "/"+  f)
    # test
    for f in testfiles:
        # get filename
        copyfile(p + "/"+  f, str(tdir) + "/val/" + str(classname) + "/" + f)
        #os.remove(p + "/"+  f)
```